# REDIS node doesn't update its IP in cluster-config-file

Tags: redis

I have a REDIS cluster consisting of 3 masters and 3 slaves. Platform configuration on which REDIS nodes run is such that a node can change IP when it is restarted.

After restart of a node, 5 other nodes correctly update the IP address of restarted node, but that particular node keeps old IP address in its configuration.

What should be made so that the node that has changed the IP updates its configuration?